# Flutter FCM push notification show the blank screen when user tap on Notification in killed state

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When user tap on push notification in termination state of app then it will open blank screen and app stuck on this screen and when app is in background then it will navigate the user in desire screen so I face issue in killed state that app will stuck on blank screen when user tap on push notification.

Comment: hello, have you found the solution?

Comment: no I did not find any solution @Sandeep

Comment: For app active state and background state, widget tree will be exist and navigating to correct screen. When in killed state, that route will not exists and trying to navigate to that screen..So it got null exception, results in blank screen. I got same issue and found this as cause. I didn't find any solution yet.

Comment: keep try { } and catch(exp){} block to avoid white screen. Check my answer below.

Comment: If anyone found a solution for this, please share your solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For app active state and background state, widget tree will be exist and navigating to correct screen. When in killed state, that route will not exists and trying to navigate to that screen..So it got null exception, results in blank screen. I got same issue and found this as main cause.

I used try and catch block to catch exception and avoid null pointer exception. So initial route screen is loading without white screen now.

```
try
 {
   // actual code here.
 }
 catch(exp)
 {
   // catch exception here
   print("exception in app kill state is $exp");
 }
```